# Trace an IP Address and find the owner

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-c++

Is there any way to find the owner or the domain Example   if i give the ip of google my tool find that ip of google  this shoul be done  address programatically most prefered programing language will be vc++  other language is also not a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword of what you are seeking seems to be **WHOIS**

This information can typically be queried for "free" at the various Internet registrites such as [ARIN](http://ws.arin.net/whois/) (American Registry for Internet Number), [RIPE](http://www.ripe.net/db/whois.html) (for Europe) etc.

However, given the distributed nature of these registries, the relatively heterogeneous format of the data stored/returned and the difficulties associated with identifying the "true" entities found at given address (i.e. rather than finding their ISP company...), several commercial services such as [Whois API](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/) are proposing various level of services to supply this info by way of a unified interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but what You are looking for is probably reverse dns look up.